# PHP:PDO: Why wont my data insert?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, pdo

I dont no what the problem is with my code.  It doesn't insert the data into the database.  Here it is.

```
$adduser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO 'basicuserinfo'(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname)");
    $adduser->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $adduser->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $adduser->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
    $adduser->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
    $adduser->execute();
```

Comment: connect the way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and find out

Comment: oh wait, it's easier. remove `'`s from table name. and get yourself a book on basic SQL syntax

Comment: @YourCommonSense the table name could be case-sensitive and the problem might be the lack of space between 'basicuserinfo' to '('. Second, I would recommend changing `$adduser->bindValue(':email', $email);` to: `$adduser->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);` and do so with all the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO 'basicuserinfo'(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname)`

That isn't a valid SQL statement. Get rid of the `'`s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is succeeding? You aren't checking the execute as in:

```
if(!$adduser->execute()) echo "Execute failed";
```

You will likely find that it is throwing an error on the ' around the table name.

Comment: This code shouldn't be. The correct way is described in the tag wiki.

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
$adduser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `basicuserinfo`(email, password, firstname, lastname) 
                         VALUES(?, ? , ? , ? )");
$adduser->bindParam('ssss', $email,$password , $firstname,$lastname);
$adduser->execute();
```

In this way of prepare statement you can reduce your executing time..

then dont put apostapy before the tablename